# How to determine distance between devices using Google Nearby Messages API for iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, google-nearby

I sincerely hope I'm just missing something in the API, but is there a way to determine distance between 2 devices using Google Nearby Messages for iOS?

I understand that Nearby Messages uses a variety of mediums to determine if devices are in close proximity (wifi, BLE, sound) and whether they can connect, which may actually be why it doesn't offer a way to determine distance between devices, perhaps they simply can't do it reliably..

If anyone can offer insight as to how I might determine distance between devices using Google Nearby Messages API for iOS, or perhaps some other recommended way, I would be very grateful!

edit: I found the place in the Android API that includes distance as a property on messages. It might just be the case that the iOS API doesn't have distance yet, which is a bummer.

Comment: Can you please share where did you find `distance as a property on messages`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precise distance isn't something the API on either iOS or Android supports at the moment. The most precision we provide is earshot (i.e. audio range) vs radio.

[Precise distance turns out to be quite a hard problem in general, and something we're often researching better solutions to...]

Comment: Anxiously awaiting the day distance comes to Google Nearby. Until then, Core Bluetooth it is!

Comment: I should have mentioned before that if you're looking for distance from a beacon or a BLE advertising device (approximated from RSSI), you can do this on Android using the onDistanceChanged callback in MessageListener (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/MessageListener#onDistanceChanged(com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.Message, com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.Distance). Having parity with this on iOS is planned, but isn't available yet as you mention.

Comment: How about Relative Distance? Of 3 devices, which is closest? (as opposed to absolute distance..)

Comment: Is Distance in Nearby still not implemented for Android Devices?